# Use PHP and cURL to login to a site without login form

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use cURL to login to a site without a login form. To login, you have to go to:

```
example.com/index.php?version=1.74&premium=true&user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&model=iPhone&sv=5.0.1
```

Honestly, I have no idea where to start. I've gone through many cURL articles and none explains doing a login without a form.

Comment: but this is not secure because the URL might be saved in the browser's history!

Answer (score 2):

A form has fields. It also has a HTTP method (usually POST).

In that case, it seems that the data is being posted by the GET method (as query strings in the URL).

You just have to build that URL (look for the `http_build_query()` built-in function) and request it using regular CURL calls. Most probably, you'll also need to accept (and keep sending) the cookie with the session information the server sends you. For that you'll need to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` values using [`curl_setopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).